# How to setup any device to verify SSL certificates using Unity3d Mono

Tags: c#, ssl, unity-game-engine, mono

Preferably without using 3rd party libraries, what is the best way to:

1. Programmatically populate Mono's Trust store for any OS/device (phone, tablet, laptop)
2. Use SslStream's RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
3. Validate the certificate of type System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate against a store containing certificates of type Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate

How do you avoid PartialChain errors and download Intermediate certificates?